# How to convert an XFS file system to HFS+

Tags: 14.04, files, xfs

I have repeatedly convinced of the reliability of the XFS file system , and I was more than satisfied . I was happy with everything in Ubuntu 14.04 ( great software) , but there is a little "but ! " Basically, I work on OSX-Mavericks 10.9.3, which sees very Windows 8.1 and works wonders with NTFS, but does not see Ubuntu!

Briefly describe the equipment:

- ASRock B75 Pro3-M i5
- 3330 GeForce GTX 650 Ti
- SATA 500GB running OS X Mavericks + Clover - a boot disk
- Toshiba 2TB running Windows 8.1 (x64) and Ubuntu 14.04 (amd64)

If you boot from the Toshiba (where there is Ubuntu and boot Windows + GRUB) after restart boot from Clover, it is impossible. Tried a lot of options - as Clover installation and boot priority, and various settings for GRUB, but have not found an acceptable option and have no desire to reinstall again Clover (Mavericks reboots 20 seconds - excellent!) So please help on the file system - how to convert from XFS to HFS+ journaled. Mavericks to saw it all synced on Mac. Thank you for the sensible answer and help!

<sup>[Originally in Russian.](https://askubuntu.com/posts/474181/revisions)</sup>

Comment: Note this is an English only site and we have no idea what you are trying to say... This question will be closed unless you translate this to English!

Answer (score 2):

You can not directly convert XFS to HFS+. So you will need to copy all of the files. Writing to HFS+ from Linux is not recommended. So you will have to use an intermediate file system:

- Repartition one of your drives to make a new partition and format it as FAT
- Boot Linux and copy files from XFS to FAT
- Reboot to OS X and copy files from FAT to HFS+

You will lose file permissions and ownership meta data. If you care, pack the files using `tar` in Linux, and then unpack them in OS X.